# Как отправить запрос в контроллер laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

Есть контроллер PostController и post.blade.php
 Как отправить ajax запрос контроллеру ?

```
  $('#target').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
    url: 'Что сюда писать ???',        
    method: 'get',            
    dataType: 'html',          
    data: {text: 'Текст'},    
    success: function(data){   
        alert(data);
    }
});
});
```

В контроллере

```
public function ajax()
    {
        return 'Данные приняты - ' . $_GET['text'];
    }
```

Comment: `{{ route('ваш роут') }}` либо конкретный юрл

Answer (score 3):

В твоем случае

```
$.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('wrapper')
            }
        });

 $('#target').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
  url: '/post/ajax',  //Как пример, можно  просто /ajax. Тогда в роуте тоже исправь      
  method: 'get',            
  dataType: 'html',          
  data: {text: 'Текст'},    
  success: function(data){   
  alert(data);
  } }); });
```

В роуте

```
Route::get('/post/ajax', 'PostController@ajax');
```

В твоем контроллере

```
public function ajax(Request $request)
{
    return 'Данные приняты - ' . $request->text;
}
```

Comment: А токен передать забыли?

Comment: Да) конечно, я даже не подумал что человек может это не учесть. Поправил.