# Как отправить данные формы с помощью AJAX в формате JSON?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, ооп, mvc

Пишу MVC приложение на php, не могу понять как прочитать данные с формы используя ajax в формате json. jquery подключил. Создал файл ajax.js, тоже подключил, вот теперь не могу понять как связать ajax и mvc. За меня делать не прошу, может кто подскажет куда просто копать дальше?
Код формы main.tpl.php

```
      <form action="" class="form-signin" id="form__signin" method="post">
          <input type="hidden" class="form__input" name="action" value="login">
          <?php if(!empty($pageData['error'])) :?>
        <p> <?php echo $pageData['error']; ?></p>
        <p> <?php endif; ?></p>
          <input type="text" class="form__input" name="login" id="login_sign" placeholder="Логин" required>
          <input type="password" class="form__input" name="password" id="password_sign" placeholder="Пароль" required>
          <button type="submit" id="signinbutton" class="form__button">Войти</button>
      </form>
```

Код IndexController на проверку

```
public function index() {
    $this->pageData['title'] = "Вход в личный кабинет";

    if (!empty($_POST)) {
        $action = $_POST['action'];
        switch ($action) {
            case 'login':
                if(!$this->login()) {
                    $this->pageData['error'] = "Неправильный логин или пароль";
                }
                break;
            case 'register':
                if($this->register()) {
                    $this->pageData['registerMsg'] = "Регистрация прошла успешно. Пройдите авторизацию!";
                }
                else {
                    $this->pageData['registerMsg'] = "Ошибка регистрации";
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    $this->view->render($this->pageTpl, $this->pageData);
}

public function ajax() {
    //не могу понять как обработать этот запрос
}


public function login() {
    if(!$this->model->checkUser()) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

IndexModel:

```
public function checkUser() {
    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = :login AND password = :password";
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);//Подготавливает запрос к выполнению и возвращает связанный с этим запросом объект
    $stmt->bindValue(":login", $login, PDO::PARAM_STR); //Связывает параметр с заданным значением
    $stmt->bindValue(":password", $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute(); //Запускает подготовленный запрос на выполнение

    $res = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if(!empty($res)) {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['login'];
        header("Location: cabinet");
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Файл AJAX

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#form__signin').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index',
            method: 'post',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {text: 'Текст'},
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            } }); });
});
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1072850/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%80-laravel

Comment: @u_mulder только там используется токен и вообще Laravel

Comment: Контроллер похож на код фреймверка Laravel, если это так, то ваш IndexModel просто дикий треш... Покажите код ajax :)

Comment: И что мешает сделать по аналогии с вопросом?

Comment: @u_mulder просто если делать по аналогии тоже нужно использовать токен?

Comment: А зачем тебе токен?

Comment: @Jour вот, понимаю что г****, это я пытался тестить элементарное получение данных, не вышло

 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('ok');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Test',
            data: new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result)
            }
        });
    });
});

Comment: @u_mulder тогда отлично, попытаюсь сделать, спасибо!

Comment: Не надо писать код в комментариях, ссылка [edit] работает.

Comment: @u_mulder отредактировал вопрос, добавил код файла ajax, но не могу понять как обработать это на стороне контроллера, смотрю в консоль ajax мне просто код страницы html отправляет

Comment: В `url: 'index',` надо указать урл, который будет обработан функцией `ajax()` из контроллера.